# How do I incorporate both actionscripts and flash animation into a flash builder project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I am planning on making a casual educational game and was looking to do that on the flash platform for broad exposure. I am wondering what are some guidelines to determine if it is warranted to create the project purely in flash or puruse a combined Flash/Flash builder project?

How can I include all my graphics and animation files as well as my AS classes into a builder project? Does it even make sense to do that. I read that creating UIs and connecting things is simpler in Flash builder and I plan to have some interaction with the client and central server where some basic data wouold be stored? Is this a good candidate for a combined flash/flash builder approach?

Also I want this to be launched on mobile and desktop platforms if that makes a difference

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Cehck these links [1](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e97-6e5d439512e1414e588-8000.html), [2](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/sharing-projects-flashbuilder-flash.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export all assets, made in Flash IDE to .swc file, and then attach this file to FlashBuilder Project using "ProjectProperties"->"Actionscript Build Path"->"Add SWC..." dialog. After-that you'll be able to create instances of the animated symbols within Flash Builder.